# SalesForce: Export SOQL query results to CSV

Tags: csv, salesforce

How to export results from an SOQL query to CSV? Currently I'm using workbench.developerforce.com but I get an error when I try to use Bulk CSV.

```
Failed: InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED: Foreign Key Relationships not supported in Bulk Query
```

I'm guessing the Bulk API doesn't support queries with relationships, it's fine with single tables though.

I also tried using the Developer Console Query Editor but there is no option to export the results to CSV. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer.aspx) has an option to export SOQL query results as CSV.

It can export the SOQL query results as CSV. This will handle paging through all the query results for you.
[image: FuseIT SFDC Explorer Export SOQL results to CSV]

Disclosure: I work for the company that makes this product. It is free to download and use.

Comment: Thank you for this link @Daniel Ballinger. I was able to export data for a simple select query. But for queries that includes aggregates and relationships I seem to get this error.

**Failed to create an instance of FuseIT.G4S.SalesforceConnector.Entities.GenericSalesforceEntity from AggregateResult -> Invalid Salesforce Id field:**

I believe I need to download the SalesForce connector but I can't seem to find a download for it. Or is it a paid service?

Comment: Can you provide a sample aggregate query that causes the error? I might need to create a patch for it.

Comment: It's a simple aggregate query: **`select count(id) cnt from Object__CustomerTag__c`**. For queries with relationships I tried this one: **`select sum(Object__Checkout__r.Object__Price__c) price
from Object__CustomerTag__c`**. Both yield the same error as above comment.

Comment: @makidev Thanks for reporting that bug. I've reproduced it and will get a fix out in the next release. In the short term, try removing the alias from the query. E.g. `select count(id) from Object__CustomerTag__c` should work.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thank you for pointing this tool out. It's made life easier compared to the Data Loader SFDC provides.

Answer (score 0):

Though its very old post:

v39.0 API is currently supporting `Relationship fields`.

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_using_bulk_query.htm

v39.0 API - Bulk API query doesn’t support the following SOQL:

- COUNT
- ROLLUP
- SUM
- GROUP BY CUBE
- OFFSET
- Nested SOQL queries

---

For v38.0 API:-
Bulk API query doesn’t support the following SOQL:
COUNT

- ROLLUP
- SUM
- GROUP BY CUBE
- OFFSET
- Nested SOQL queries
- ***Relationship fields***